# In a MySQL CLI, is there a way to autocomplete procedures?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, command-line-interface, procedure

For example, autocomplete allows you to type this:

```
select cu<TAB> from o<TAB> where nu<TAB> = 42;
```

And the result can be this:

```
select customer_name from orders where number = 42;
```

I would like to be able to do that with created procedures (and functions), which tend to have long names:

```
call getCustomerByOrderNumber(42);
```

I cannot find any answers on how to do this. I am using a MySQL CLI on an SSH connection. Running the `rehash` (or `\#`) command to rehash the autocompletion list only seems to work for table and column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct — the rehash feature in the `mysql` client hashes schemas, tables, and columns, but not other objects (procedures, triggers, functions, events).

You can confirm this by reading the source for the `build_completion_hash()` function in mysql.cc.

Reference: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/client/mysql.cc#L3142-L3250

Feel free to file a feature request at bugs.mysql.com. Or better yet, implement it yourself and contribute a patch.

On the other hand, the MySQL developers might turn down the feature request, because they would like new development to focus on MySQL Shell instead of the old `mysql` client.